# How to use table of different database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to transport  some tables(16 tables) to another database and there are a number of stored procedures(200 tables) which use these tables.

Transporting stored procedures to another database is not preferred.

For my case:

`dbA` contains  `sp_xyz` stored procedure, `tableB` and `tableC` tables.

and content of `sp_xyz` can be :

```
 SELECT A.column1, B.column2 
 FROM
 tableB A 
 JOIN tableC B ON A.fk_b_id = B.id
```

we want to transport `tableC` to dbB. So how should I change this sp with minimum change.

Comment: You should avoid using `sp_` as a prefix for stored procedures in SQL Server. It's reserved for Microsofts use (it stands for "system procedure", not stored procedure), and they're slower to access than other names (because `master` is searched before the current database). In general, you shouldn't *need* to use prefixes for objects in SQL - just the position of an object in a query or statement should inform you on what type of object it is (exception: tables and views - but they *should* be interchangable anyway)

Comment: dont forget to mark it as accepted if you got the info you want

Comment: @PranayRana I know how to mark. But I prefer to mark question answer 2 days later because I need to see every candidate answer. I have already vote your answer;)

Comment: @PranayRana What do you think about creating view of this tables? and stored procedutes reach this table via its view? – ibrahimyilmaz 15 hours ago

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use a table in another database then you can do like this in sql server when the database is on same server:

```
Select * from [DBName].[Schema].[Table]
```

If the database is in another server, specify the linked server name too:

```
Select * from [DBServer].[DBName].[Schema].[Table]
```

Schema name - replace by your schema which is "dbo" by default in sql server.

Comment: kindly correct me if it is schema.db or db.schema as i tried with db.schema and it worked for me...

Comment: @sfah - its mistake its db.schema

Answer (score 1):

I tried a query for this and found that you can use

```
SELECT * FROM DB_Name.Schema.Table_Name
```

e-g

```
SELECT * FROM abcDB.dbo.address
```